# Segment dyed cells from digital pathology images using Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation, watershed, image-thresholding

I am trying to segment colored cells from original images like this:

[image]

The blue colored cells are targets that I want to segment and counted.

Here is the code I use:

```
global ButtonDown

img=imread('Zoom.png');
hsv=rgb2hsv(img);
s=hsv(:,:,2);
bw = imbinarize(s,graythresh(s));
figure

imshow(bw)
se=strel('disk',5);
bw2=imclose(bw,se);
bw3=bwareaopen(bw2,200);
figure
imshow(bw3);

D=-bwdist(~bw3);
mask=imextendedmin(D,2);
D2=imimposemin(D,mask);
Ld=watershed(D);
Water_splited=bw3;
Water_splited(Ld==0)=0;
%axes(handles.axes1);
show_img=Water_splited;
figure
imshow(show_img)


if ButtonDown == 1
 pos = get(handles.axes1, 'CurrentPoint');
 row=floor(pos(1,2));
 col=floor(pos(1,1));
 Diy_splited=show_img;
 Diy_splited(row,col)=0;
 show_img=Diy_splited;
 axes(handles.axes1);
 imshow(show_img);
end
```

I used a watershed algorithm to segment adherent cells, however, over-segmentation occurred.
The results are:

[image]

So how to avoid this over-segmentation issue?

Comment: Over segmentation? You are just segmenting a small part of that image you posted, right? somewhere the top left part these cells are there with the same shape

Comment: I think Haoyang meant the multiple lines for the bottom right cell. Well, I ran the code and did not get the same image. If you can, make the code work with the image you gave so we can see what went wrong

Comment: Hi Yuval, thank you for your notice. I realized that I posted wrong original images and I re-uploaded the correct one and know the codes should work.